# PyMC, deterministic nodes in loops

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

I'm a bit new to Python and PyMC, and making rapid progress. But I'm just confused about the use of setting deterministic values of a 2D matrix. I have a model below, that I cannot get to parse correctly. The problem relates to setting the value `theta` in the model.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc
```

define known variables

```
N = 2
T = 10
tau = 1
```

define model... which I cannot get to parse correctly. It's the allocation of `theta` that I'm having trouble with. The aim to to get samples of D and x. Theta is just an intermediate variable, but I need to keep it as it's used in more complex variations of the model.

```
def NAFCgenerator():

    D = np.empty(T, dtype=object)
    theta = np.empty([N,T], dtype=object)
    x = np.empty([N,T], dtype=object)

    # true location of signal
    for t in range(T):
        D[t] = pymc.DiscreteUniform('D_%i' % t, lower=0, upper=N-1)

    for t in range(T):
        for n in range(N):
            @pymc.deterministic(plot=False)
            def temp_theta(dt=D[t], n=n):
                return dt==n
            theta[n,t] = temp_theta

            x[n,t] = pymc.Normal('x_%i,%i' % (n,t),
                               mu=theta[n,t], tau=tau)

    return locals()
```

** EDIT **

Explicit indexing is useful for me as I'm learning both PyMC and Python. But it seems that extracting MCMC samples is a bit clunky, e.g.

```
D0values = pymc_generator.trace('D_0')[:]
```

But I am probably missing something. But did I managed to get a vectorised version working

```
# Approach 1b - actually quite promising
def NAFCgenerator():

# NOTE TO SELF. It's important to declare these as objects
D = np.empty(T, dtype=object)
theta = np.empty([N,T], dtype=object)
x = np.empty([N,T], dtype=object)

# true location of signal
D = pymc.Categorical('D', spatial_prior, size=T)

# displayed stimuli
@pymc.deterministic(plot=False)
def theta(D=D):
    theta = np.zeros([N,T])
    theta[0,D==0]=1
    theta[1,D==1]=1
    return theta

#for n in range(N):    
x = pymc.Normal('x', mu=theta, tau=tau)

return locals()
```

Which seems easier to get at MCMC samples using this for example

```
Dvalues = pymc_generator.trace('D')[:]
```

Comment: When I execute your code (with `m = pymc.MCMC(NAFCgenerator())`), I get this error: `ValueError: A tallyable PyMC object called temp_theta already exists. This will cause problems for some database backends.`  Is this the problem you are seeing?  You should add it to your question, to make it easier for people to help.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, will be more explicit in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyMC2, when creating deterministic nodes with decorators, the default is to take the node name from the function name.  The solution is simple: specify the node name as a parameter for the decorator.

```
        @pymc.deterministic(name='temp_theta_%d_%d'%(t,n), plot=False)
        def temp_theta(dt=D[t], n=n):
            return dt==n
        theta[n,t] = temp_theta
```

Here is [a notebook that puts this in context](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/ea054090465548c7cab5).

Comment: Thanks, being able to use explicit indexing is useful for me, coming from JAGS. It seems that extracting the MCMC samples is more clumsy though, requiring lines like
`pymc_generator.trace('D_0')[:]` etc
I'll add a vectorised version that I managed to get working.